# How do aggregate functions in pandas work?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to understand what is going on under the hood with `groupby` and aggregating functions in pandas. For example, here are timing results for 4 different ways to get sum by group:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.random.randint(0,3,10),
                   'b': np.random.rand(10)})

%timeit df.groupby('a')['b'].sum()
1000 loops, best of 3: 287 µs per loop

%timeit df.groupby('a')['b'].agg(sum)
1000 loops, best of 3: 296 µs per loop

%timeit df.groupby('a')['b'].apply(sum)
1000 loops, best of 3: 700 µs per loop

%timeit df.groupby('a')['b'].apply(lambda x: x.sum())
1000 loops, best of 3: 743 µs per loop
```

From time alone, it looks like `.sum()` and `.agg(sum)` are pretty similar, but `.apply(sum)` and `.apply(lambda x: x.sum())` take more than twice as long.

Are these doing very different things in the background?

Comment: I think all is hidden [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/groupby.py). 4210 lines.

Comment: Thanks. I'm hoping perhaps someone who has a good understanding of this could summarize though. My python is not quite up to the level of being able to understand what the source is doing, but it's certainly a good learning opportunity.

Answer (score 3):

My two cents:

`agg(F)` simply calls `aggregate(F)`. Firstly, `aggregate()` will be determined if `F` is `cython` function (or an equivalent `cython` function exists).  If so, `aggregate(F)` becomes a call to the `.F` method of the `groupby` object, which is an optimized `cython` method.  There are only a number of functions that will be treated this way, the full list is defined by `_cython_table` dictionary towards the very end of the source code. `sum` is one of them.

Obviously, using `cython` function means things tends to run faster.  With `.agg(F)`, however, it will need to run a few more lines of codes, and therefore is going to be slightly slower than `.F()`, even `F` is in the `_cython_table` and a `.F` method exsits.

`apply(F)` calles `_python_apply_general`.  As the name implies, it is ageneral propose method.  Under the hood, it does not attempt checking if a faster `cython` version of aggerate function exists.  It applies `F` to each group and assembles the results together, which means it would run slower than the optimized `cython` version equivalent (such as `.sum`).

Finally, `apply(lambda x: F(x))` will be slightly slower than `apply(F)` due to the additional `lambda` function.